# How to manipulate style for a div during js process?

Tags: javascript, css

Just go for a few loops and then display different value for a given DIV but the style for this DIV failed to be set dynamically, any idea? How to fix it?  Fyi, the style section, i have set it for this DIV as well.  But once the value changes the style is gone (style set via the Style section is no longer valid).
Thanks.

```
var i = 60;                     //  set your counter to 60

function myLoop () {           //  create a loop function
   setTimeout(function () {    //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called
    if (i < 100) {
        i += 10;                   //  increment the counter by 10
        console.log(i);
// document.getElementById('score').style = "margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-right: -50%; font-size: 216px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);color: red;";
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = i; 
         myLoop();             //  ..  again which will trigger another 
     } 
   }, 3000)

}
```

Comment: really you should only need to assign a css class to the score DIV, or if it's not a DIV, assign a class to the DIV that contains score

Comment: Why not just `<style>#score {margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-right: -50%; font-size: 216px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);color: red;}</style>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.style` refers to the style property object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) , not the attribute. try

```
document.getElementById('score').setAttribute("style", 
"margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-right: -50%; font-size: 216px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);color: red;");
```

Comment: Very nice.  No error.  And when I removed the "transform: translate(-50%, -50%)" attribute it works.  But oddly, not sure why the number 80 was skipped, tested with Chrome and Firefox with same result.  Thanks.

Comment: "But oddly, not sure why the number 80 was skipped", resolved, it's the speed.